# Django "NULLS LAST" for creating Indexes

Tags: python, django, indexing, django-models, null

Django 1.11 and later allow using `F`-expressions for adding `nulls last` option to queries:

```
queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by(F('wealth').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

However, we want to use this functionality for creating Indexes. A standard Django Index inside a model definition:

```
indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['-wealth']),
]
```

---

I tried something along the lines of:

```
indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=[models.F('wealth').desc(nulls_last=True)]),
]
```

which returns `AttributeError: 'OrderBy' object has no attribute 'startswith'`.

Is this possible to do using `F`-expressions in Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately, that is currently (Django <=2.1) not possible. If you look at the [source of `models.Index`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/indexes/#Index), you will see that it assumes that the argument `fields` contains model names and nothing else.

As a workaround, you could manually create your index with raw SQL in a migration.

Comment: seems like added in 2.2 ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/indexes/#condition

Comment: There is a PR to add functional indexes and solve this problem
https://github.com/django/django/pull/11929

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately it is now possible to create functional indexes since Django 3.2. The example which you posted has to be adjusted a little by moving the field from `fields` to `*expressions` and by adding a name, which is required when using expressions.

```
indexes = [
    Index(F('wealth').desc(nulls_last=True), name='wealth_desc_idx'),
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#expressions